# Find the (asymmetric) set-difference of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a function which compute the difference of two lists as multi-sets. For example, [1,2,2,3]-[1,2,3,4]=[2]. I defined the following in python.

```
def SetDifferenceListDifference(A,B): # A-B, can have duplicate elements
    r=[]
    r1=list(set(A))
    for i in r1:
        t1=A.count(i)-B.count(i)
        #print(t1)
        for j in range(1,t1+1):
            r.append(i)
    return r
```

Is there a faster way in python to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean with "compute the difference"? The difference here would be `4`, since that digit is only present in the second set.

Comment: @iuvbio, thank you very much. For two multi-sets A, B, I denote by A-B the set of elements in A but not in B as multi-sets.

Answer (score 8):

Some style issues:

- Function names should be snake_case, not PascalCase.
- Function arguments should be lower case.
- The operators need more space.
- There's no documentation comment to explain what the function does, or to show examples.

---

This looks like it could be greatly simplified using the Standard Library's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

Here's how you would use `Counter` to perform the same operation, complete with unit tests:

```
from collections import Counter

def subtract_multiset(a, b):
    '''
    Return a copy of a with the elements of b removed.

    >>> subtract_multiset([], [0, 1])
    []
    >>> subtract_multiset(["x", "x", "y"], [])
    ['x', 'x', 'y']
    >>> subtract_multiset(["ham", "spam", "eggs", "spam", "spam"], ["spam", "spam"])
    ['ham', 'spam', 'eggs']
    >>> subtract_multiset([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1])
    [0]
    >>> subtract_multiset([1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
    [2]
    '''

    diff = Counter(a) - Counter(b)
    return list(diff.elements())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

This scales better as we increase the length of the lists:

- The question code calls `list.count()` on both `A` and `B` inside the loop, which executes for every element in the set `r1`.  So it scales as O(N²) where N is the total number of elements, assuming the number of unique elements in `A` is proportional to the size of `A`.
- Constructing the counters looks at each element once, with a `log N` lookup (pretty similar to constructing the `set` in the original implementation).  But after that, the counter subtraction and listing of elements has smaller impact, so overall performance tends to O(N log N).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all styling suggestions made by Toby. However, the OP asked for ways to make his implementation **faster**. Using `Counter` is indeed nice, but it's considerably slower than the OP's original approach. By making some slight adjustments to the original it can be made even faster.

My suggestion:

```py
def set_difference_opt(a: list[Any], b: list[Any]) -> list[Any]:
    """Return elements of 'a' that are not in 'b'."""
    diffs = []
    for v in set(a):
        diff = a.count(v) - b.count(v)
        diffs.extend([v] * diff)
    return diffs
```

Benchmark:

```py
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: set_difference(s1, s2)))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: set_difference_opt(s1, s2)))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: subtract_multiset(s1, s2)))
```

```
Original approach:
0.7215887490019668
Original optimized:
0.5921416310011409
Using collections:
2.7791459890140686
```

**Edit**

That's only the case when both inputs are small though. Here's the results for two arrays with random integers between 1 and 10 of size 100:

```
Original approach:
13.11639182100771
Original optimized:
12.332467784988694
Using collections:
7.758293374994537
```

So most likely, using `Counter` is what you'll want.

Comment: Are `s1` and `s2` the lists shown in the question?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, for the first benchmark they are the lists from the question.

Comment: I've added some notes on scalability to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On top the existing reviews, here are few more points mostly about style.

#### Use descriptive names

It's good to give descriptive names to variables to help readers understand their purpose. For example:

- `r` is the difference of the input elements, `diff` would describe that better
- `i` is actually a number, `num` would describe it better

  - Note that `i` is commonly used as the index variable in a counting loop
- `t` is the count difference of the number of occurrences, so it could be `count_diff`
- `r1` is ... well it's only used once so you could just inline it in `for num in set(A): ...`

#### Do not create unnecessary list

Creating a list here is unnecessary:

> ```
> r1=list(set(A))
> for i in r1:
> ```

You can iterate over a `set` directly:

```
for num in set(A):
```

#### Use simpler form of range

In this loop:

> ```
> for j in range(1,t1+1):
>     r.append(i)
> ```

The values of the range are not used, and since the default starting value of `range(x)` is 0, `range(t1)` is equivalent to `range(1, t1 + 1)`.

Also, when the variable of a range loop is not used,
it's customary in Python to give it the name `_`:

```
for _ in range(t1):
    r.append(i)
```

#### Use simpler way to create a list of the same character

Instead of:

> ```
> for j in range(1,t1+1):
>     r.append(i)
> ```

This is equivalent and shorter:

```
r.extend([i] * t1)
```